# Reporting template for universal windows App

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, reporting

All the data shown in the screen shot are fields in a table.

I am trying to display these fields in `UWP` in a report page inside my app.
I have tried displaying it on a page using `xaml` and binding to the appropriate fields but the outcome of the view was not pretty as i expected.

Any suggestions for report templates in UWP that I could
use to do create something like the screen shot below? [image]

Comment: What have you done? Could you please show your xaml code? In general, you could use the `Grid` control to make your table and use `TextBlock`, `Image` controls etc. to fill the content.

Comment: I did exactly what you mentioned earlier, however i have seen what i am looking for, synfusion has report viewers that make use of rdlc files, the tutorial for uwp is not comprehensive enough, i am still looking at other options aside syncfusion.